# How to get query string parameter value in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, query-string

I'm trying to get a query string value using:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["data"]
```

but it fails with error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'QueryString'

QueryString is from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, you should rely on model-binding to access incoming values, not read them explicitly from a certain request source.

However, the correct way to read query-string values is through `Request.Query` instead. And in your case:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["data"]
```

See [Model-Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["data"][0]`

Comment: Model-Binding is the ticket, glad you made that point.